# Java-Android / How to dynamically add plots to an AchartEngine chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I have 2 Fragments, one with my chart and below one with a TableLayout with my TimeChart values. I would like to add to my chart, a function when i click (or hover) one value of my table, a plot draw himself on the chart at specific date and value but i didn't find yet a way to do this. Could some have already done something like that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this. One option would be that you add an extra series that would contain only the extra point you want to render. When you want to render it at another location, just remove the previous one and add another one. Don't forget to call `chartView.repaint();` after every such change.